# Remove attributes from AD schema?

Tags: active-directory, schema

Can we edit a scheme in Active Directory?

Scheme cannot be deleted. But is there any possibility of editing?

For e.g. If the user object schema has 30 attributes, but i need only 10 attributes in it. Is there any possibility to delete or remove attributes from the user class schema/

Answer (score 2):

While it might be theoretical possible (I don't know if it is), it's an extremely bad idea. AD expects to have at least the attributes in the default schema available and there is no telling what might go wrong if some of them are missing.

I don't see why you want to do this anyway. If you don't need them, don't use them.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to delete an attribute from an Active Directory schema. [**The only supported/guaranteed way to roll back a schema change is a full forest recovery.**](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/05/28/best-practices-for-implementing-schema-updates-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-forest-recovery.aspx)   (There was one, unsupported way to do it prior to Windows 2000 SP4, but the option was completely removed in SP4, so not anymore).

The closest you can come is to modify an attribute to be "defunct" by setting `isDefunct` to `TRUE` in the schema.

But, there's generally no reason to - why would you bother?

Comment: Well, schemas change. You wouldn't expect a table with data in SQLite or MySql to stay the same throughout the lifespan of your application. A company that uses AD to integrate their business may add custom attributes, and there would be no reason for them not to have the option to delete their own custom attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Edit to your heart's content using adsiedit, but the potential for breaking things is extremely high if you're unfamiliar with the changes you're making.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

View adsiedit as a last resort tool, to be used only under conditions where you know exactly what you're doing.